# Magento, grid, add column with link to a website

Tags: magento, hyperlink, grid, magento-1.7

I'm banging my head to add a plain, simple link to a website on a custom column of a grid. I used the [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/) to add a custom renderer for the column and it works. I though that just modifying the render and adding a  tag will be enough. But my hopes were dashed, is not working.

How can be this done? Should be simple, but no way I can find how. I found lot of question/answers here in SO but about adding links to products, categories, etc, no reference to external websites, maybe I'm just using the wrong keywords in the search.

Here is the _prepareColumns() from my Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {
    $blog = Mage::getModel('blogtest/blog');

    $this->addColumn('api_blog_url', array(
            'header' => $this->__('URL'),
            'align' => 'center',
            'index' => 'api_blog_url',
            'width' => 50,
            'type' => 'text',
            'renderer' =>  'Dts_Blogtest_Block_Adminhtml_Blog_Renderer_MyRender'
    ));
....
```

And here is my render override for that column:

```
<?php
class Dts_Blogtest_Block_Adminhtml_Blog_Renderer_MyRender extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
//      return '<a href="http://'.$value.'>'.$value.'</a>';
        return '<span style="color:red;">'.$value.'</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why can't u use "action" in grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the style with color red it working properly but if you uncomment the line with the `<a href..>` it is not?

I think you just missed a quote in the href attribute.

```
return '<a href="http://'.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Btw, i think, that you can write more good looking code, if will be use next approach: In render function you create a block and send link-data. After, you create block and template for this block. In template you get link-data and display it as you wish.

```
<?php
class Something
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $column_data = $row->getData(
            $this->getColumn()->getIndex()
        );

        return $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('something/adminhtml_renderer_link')
                ->setLink($column_data )
                    ->_toHtml();
    }
}
?>

<?php
class Something
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('something/link.phtml');
    }
}
?>

<?php
$link = $this->getLink();
?>
<?php if ($link): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $this->__('Click to view!'); ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('No link'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```